# Cannot Access the CSS while developing in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am developing a web application using PHP and mysql.I was doing the intial development in a windows machine and now shifted to ubuntu ultimate edition.I installed apache/PHP/Mysql and configured them.
 I placed my web folder in /var/www and when I give the URL in browser,I am not getting the page with CSS.

**Not Working:**

href="./css/style.css"

**Working:**

href="style1.css"

Is there anyway where I can give a common url so that it works both in linux and windows.

Comment: This totally depends on your web root. How are you accessing the page itself? What address do you enter into the browser?

Comment: And how are you accessing your style sheets?

Comment: style sheets are inside a folder called CSS along with images.
File locations:

style.css :- /var/www/foldername/CSS
index.php :/var/www/foldername
images : /var/www/foldername/CSS/images

for it to work like
href="style1.css"
I copied the .css file and images in the

Comment: @user2 please show the HTML code you are using to embed the style sheet, and the full URLs of the pages where it works, and where it doesn't. (Remove the domain name if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

If webroot is /var/www/sitename.com

and CSS lives in /var/www/sitename.com/css

always refer to it as /css/style.css, not ./css  --  "/" is relative to the webroot not the file system.   './css' will screw you up if you're at sitename.com/page/about

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path http://localhost/[the proper path eg. css/style.css] and if it still doesn't work it's a file problem.

Check if You put the file where You expect it to be and if yes - 
try in console: `chmod 0755 style.css`

because You might be getting 403 error not 404